# Moving a socket with std::move()

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio, move-semantics

My problem is related to moving Boost.Asio sockets using `std::move`.

I'm working on a server in C++ with switchable implementations and libraries (Boost.Asio, POSIX sockets, Winsock sockets). To achieve this, I have `HttpServer` and `HttpClient` interfaces which are implemented by classes like `PosixHttpServer`, `PosixHttpClient`, `BoostHttpServer`, `BoostHttpClient`. After binding and listening on the server, the `HttpClient` would be created by `HttpServer::accept()`. I made sure to disable copying on both `HttpServer` and `HttpClient`. I'm not planning to use async operations right now.

```
// main.cpp

using HttpServerPtr = std::unique_ptr<HttpServer>;
using HttpClientPtr = std::unique_ptr<HttpClient>;

...

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ...

   //HttpServerPtr server = std::make_unique<PosixHttpServer>();
   HttpServerPtr server = std::make_unique<BoostHttpServer>();
   if (!server->bind(server_port)
   {
       ...
   }

   if (!server->listen())
   {
       ...
   }
   std::cout << "Listening to client connections at "
             << server->getAddress()
             << " on port " << std::to_string(server_port)
             << std::endl;

   while (1)
   {
       HttpClientPtr client = server->accept();
       if (!client)
       {
           std::cerr << "failed to accept" << std::endl;
           continue;
       }

       std::cout << "Got connection from "
                 << client->getAddress() << std::endl;

       // TODO: Write HTTP response
       if (!client->write("Hello World!"))
       {
           std::cerr << "failed to write" << std::endl;
       }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To decouple the client socket from the `HttpServer`, the client `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` would be stored as a member of `HttpClient`. In `BoostHttpServer::accept()`, I am able to pass the Boost.Asio socket to the `HttpClient` if I use `std::shared_ptr` (`_io_service` and `_acceptor` are private members of `HttpServer`).

```
// boosthttpserver.cpp
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

bool BoostHttpServer::bind(const uint16_t port)
{
    try
    {
        tcp::resolver resolver(_io_service);
        tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), boost::asio::ip::host_name(), std::to_string(port));

        tcp::resolver::iterator available_endpoint = resolver.resolve(query);
        tcp::resolver::iterator end;
        for (; available_endpoint != end; ++available_endpoint)
        {
            tcp::endpoint localhost = *available_endpoint;
            _acceptor.open(localhost.protocol());
            _acceptor.bind(localhost);

            _address = localhost.address().to_string();
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool BoostHttpServer::listen()
{
    try
    {
        _acceptor.listen();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

HttpClientPtr BoostHttpServer::accept()
{
    try
    {
        auto client_socket = std::make_shared<tcp::socket>(_io_service);
        _acceptor.accept(*client_socket);
        return std::make_unique<BoostHttpClient>(client_socket);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
}


// boosthttpclient.hpp
class BoostHttpClient : public HttpClient
{
public:
    BoostHttpClient(std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket);
    BoostHttpClient(const BoostHttpClient&) = delete;
    BoostHttpClient& operator=(const BoostHttpClient&) = delete;

    virtual bool write(const std::string& message) override;
    virtual std::string getAddress() const override;

private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket _socket;
    const std::string _address;
};

// boosthttpclient.cpp
BoostHttpClient::BoostHttpClient(
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket
)
    : _socket(socket)
    , _address(socket->remote_endpoint().address().to_string())
{
}
```

This is the application output when I start the server and use `telnet localhost 8080` for example:

```
Listening to connections at 127.0.0.1 on port 8080
Got connection from 127.0.0.1
```

However, I want to spare the heap allocation, create `client_socket` on the stack and transfer the ownership of it to the `BoostHttpClient` with `std::move`.

```
// boosthttpserver.cpp
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

...

HttpClientPtr BoostHttpServer::accept()
{
    try
    {
        tcp::socket client_socket(_io_service);
        _acceptor.accept(client_socket);
        return std::make_unique<BoostHttpClient>(std::move(client_socket));
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
}


// boosthttpclient.hpp
class BoostHttpClient : public HttpClient
{
public:
    BoostHttpClient(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&& socket);
    BoostHttpClient(const BoostHttpClient&) = delete;
    BoostHttpClient& operator=(const BoostHttpClient&) = delete;

    virtual bool write(const std::string& message) override;
    virtual std::string getAddress() const override;

private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket _socket;
    const std::string _address;
};

// boosthttpclient.cpp
BoostHttpClient::BoostHttpClient(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&& socket)
    : _socket(std::move(socket))
    , _address(socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string())
{
}
```

However, the socket is gone after the move. As if its destructor got called and got closed.

```
Listening to connections at 127.0.0.1 on port 8080
remote_endpoint: Bad file descriptor
failed to accept
```

I thought that it could be as easy as passing other non-copyable objects like `std::thread` or `std::mutex` as constructor parameters, but cleary there's something I don't understand what happens at `std::move(client_socket)`. Why doesn't it get transferred and why does it closes itself?

I use Boost 1.64.0, gcc version 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6) and C++17 if that matters.

Comment: You cannot expect that the call `socket.remote_endpoint()` returns valid object when `socket` object was moved in one line above. You should not use any methods for moved object. Try `_socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string()` in ctor of `BoostHttpClient`.

Comment: @rafix07 This solved my problem, the connections are now getting accepted, thanks. Although not really happy about _address inefficiently being default-constructed before reassigning in the ctor body, this is the price I have to pay for playing with esoteric C++ magic.

Comment: @BalintKiss: You can use `_socket` *in* the member initializer for `_address`, so long as they’re declared in the right order.